# Why is onLayout in custom ViewGroup called again and again?

Tags: android, android-layout

I've a custom ViewGroup, to which a custom ImageView is added as a child. Now, my problem is that whenever I change the image in the child, by overriding the onDraw(), the onLayout method in the parent is called. Is it not possible to just change the image in the child without calling the onLayout method in the Custom ViewGroup? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Interestingly, no one answers this simple question.**

The onLayout() method is called by default when the viewgroup needs to be redrawn.
see https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws.html

you can actually extend the viewgroup to implement your custom onLayout() and onMeasure() method to control the behavior it is called.